# Need to clear dropdown3 on every select

Tags: jquery, select, append

my script is working fine but problem is append which is adding options in dropdown3 on every select. I need to clear dropdown3 every time user select option in dropdown2 i tryed with html insted of append but then html is calling only 1st option from dropdown3
EDIT:
i have one more question how to empty all options but not 1st one since its disabled by default?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var kategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "kategorije.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniKategorije(kategorije){
                    $.each(kategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown2').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }

            </script>

        <script>
        $("#dropdown2").change(function(){
     var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();

        if (selectedValue == "0") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pHardware.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            }); 
           else if (selectedValue == "1") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pOperativniSistem.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            }); 
             else   if (selectedValue == "2") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pMail.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            }); 
            else    if (selectedValue == "3") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pBiAplikacija.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            });
                else    if (selectedValue == "4") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pKumunikacija.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            });
            else    if (selectedValue == "5") 
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var podKategorije;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "pPristupSistemu.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (data) {
                    popuniPodKategorije(data);
                    }
                });

                function popuniPodKategorije(podKategorije){
                    $.each(podKategorije.split("\n").slice(0,-1), function(k, v){
                        $('#dropdown3').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', k).text(v));
                    });
                }
            });
            });     
        </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('#dropdown3').empty();
```

That will remove all `<option>` elements underneath the dropdown element.

Comment: i have one more question how to empty all options but not 1st one since its disabled by default?